# Forking Java using the Exec Maven Plugin, without using the `exec` goal

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

From the [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/):

1. `exec:exec` execute programs and Java programs in a separate process.
2. `exec:java` execute Java programs in the same VM.

I want to fork a java program.  I've already got it working in `exec:java` but that doesn't fork.  So the obvious move is to change the goal to `exec`.  Problem is, the syntax for `exec` is pretty different from the syntax of `java`.  It doesn't have tags like `includeProjectDependencies`, `includePluginDependencies`, etc.  Is there a plugin I can use that is like #1 in the sense that it forks, but has a convenient syntax like #2?  IMO, #2 should just have a `<fork>true</fork>` configuration.

Comment: You could always modify the Exec Maven plugin to fork the Java process but keep includeProjectDependencies and includePluginDependencies http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecMojo.java

Comment: @DeanToader The link is now rotten away.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/85

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to spawn a Java process from Maven with the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). This plugin [exports several classpaths](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) covering the compile/runtime/test scopes, as well as the plugin dependencies.

Executing a class in a separate process with the compile and plugin dependencies would thus look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <target>
      <java classname="com.example.MainClass" fork="true">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
          <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
      </java>
    </target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is executed with `mvn antrun:run` instead of `exec:exec`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can stick to exec:exec, using that kind of configuration if you want to give the project classpath to the Java process you use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <longClasspath>true</longClasspath>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-XX:MaxPermSize=128M</argument>
            <argument>-Xmx1024M</argument>
            <argument>-Xdebug</argument>
            <argument>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also the [plugin Usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)

Comment: Where are you configuring `includeProjectDependencies` and `includePluginDependencies` here?

Comment: Project dependencies are added through <classpath/> argument. I don't think you can add plugin dependencies though, but is it really an issue?

Comment: For me it is.  I'm running a deployer.  The deployer has no business being on the actual app's classpath.

Comment: Not work for me, I ended up with IntelliJ Run/Debug Configratuion > Runner > VM Options, specify vm options for maven in the first place.

Comment: Just add the class to run as the last argument.